# Does switching to virtual pageviews affect SERPs

Tags: google-analytics

We have an ecommerce site and recently started using more seo friendly urls for category and product pages.

Our url structure before the move was:

```
/shop/some-category-name    
/product/some-product-name
```

and the url structure is now:

```
/some-category-name
/some-product-name
```

This has made it impossible to setup goal funnel steps for product pages in Google Analytics.

One solution we are looking at is to use virtual pageviews and start tracking product pages with "/product" appended again.

However, I'm not 100% sure this will affect SERPs and other organic metrics (bounce rate?).

Can anyone confirm that this will not have a negative affect on rankings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you send to Google Analytics (e.g. page views) are entirely separate from the way that your website serves content to users and bots.

Using Google Analytics virtual page views to will have no impact on anything other than your Google Analytics reports and tools that connect to the Google Analytics reporting API.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure that was the case. It's a big site so just wanted confirmation. Thanks.